# Query a table to find A OR B using REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I am trying to do a regex match to MySQL query (*actually, it MariaDB*) a table to find any word in a filepath that contains the string "!Mutex" or were the folder ends with a capital "M".

So if the cell contained the following paths.

```
-------------
|Path_Folder|
-------------------------------------------------------
|E:\folder01\folder01\folder03\!Mutex\folder05        |
|E:\folder01\folder01\folder03\folder4\!Mutex\folder06|
|E:\folder01\folder01\folder03\folder04\folderM       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm NOT trying to port this anywhere (no php), just trying to find the results.

Comment: Why a regex when a normal SQL `LIKE` could do the job? `WHERE (Path_Folder LIKE '%!Mutex%') OR (Path_Folder LIKE '%M')` should work fine, and be faster (and easier to read/maintain) than a regex.

Comment: I posted it as a answer, since it seems to work for the actual problem you're trying to solve. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for a regex solution, but sometimes that's not the answer. :-)

You can do this instead with a normal SQL `LIKE` expression.

```
SELECT 
  Path_Folder 
FROM 
  Your_Table 
WHERE 
  (Path_Folder LIKE '%!Mutex%') 
OR 
  (Path_Folder LIKE '%M')
```

A `LIKE` should work just fine for what you need, and be faster (and easier to read/maintain) than a regex.